# setting title of msgbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, messagebox, title

is it possible to change the title of the msgbox in vb.net?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use the right overloaded [version of Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z.aspx):

```
Visual Basic (Usage)
Dim text As String
Dim caption As String
Dim buttons As MessageBoxButtons
Dim returnValue As DialogResult

returnValue = MessageBox.Show(text, caption, buttons)
```

From MSDN (the `Caption` variable is the title of the MessageBox):

```
Dim Message As String = "You did not enter a server name. Cancel this operation?"
Dim Caption As String = "Error Detected in Input"
Dim Buttons As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo

Dim Result As DialogResult

'Displays the MessageBox

Result = MessageBox.Show(Message, Caption, Buttons)
```

Comment: Yeah, I said that in a parenthetical phrase above.  :)